# How to use map-deep-get in sass

Tags: css, function, sass

I was following this article https://www.sitepoint.com/better-solution-managing-z-index-sass/
But there is a missing link where it doesn't link the map-deep-get function back into the z function, and the demo doesn't work.
I've tried searching but found no help.

```
$z-layers: (
  "goku":            9001, 
  "shoryuken":       8000,
  "modal": (
    "base":           500,
    "close":          100,
    "header":          50,
    "footer":          10
  ),
  "default":            1,
  "below":             -1,
  "bottomless-pit": -9000
);

@function map-deep-get($map, $keys...) {
  @each $key in $keys {
    $map: map-get($map, $key);
  }

  @return $map;
}

@function z($layer) {
  @if not map-has-key($z-layers, $layer) {
    @warn "No layer found for `#{$layer}` in $z-layers map. Property omitted.";
  }

  @return map-get($z-layers, $layer);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## Map-deep-get

---

### Syntax

`Dart Sass syntax:`

```
@use "sass:list";
@use "sass:map";
@use "sass:meta";

@function map-deep-get($map, $keys...) {
   $scope: $map; $i: 1;
   @while (meta.type-of($scope) == map) and ($i <= list.length($keys)) {
      $scope: map.get($scope, list.nth($keys, $i));
      $i: $i + 1;
   }
   @return $scope;
}
```

`Lib Sass syntax:`

```
@function map-deep-get($map, $keys...) {
   $scope: $map; $i: 1;
   @while (type-of($scope) == map) and ($i <= length($keys)) {
      $scope: map-get($scope, nth($keys, $i));
      $i: $i + 1;
   }
   @return $scope;
}
```

### How to use:

This `map-deep-get` function let's you acces as deeply nested values as you want and can also be used as a regular `map-get` function.

```
$exampleMap: (
   "foo": foo,
   "bar": (
      "barfoo": barfoo,
      "barbar": (
         "barbarfoo": barbarfoo,
      ),
   ),
);
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/LudwigGeorgImmanuel/pen/JjbdWGG)
**Not nested item:**

```
@debug map-deep-get($exampleMap, "foo") //foo
```

**Nested item:**

```
@debug map-deep-get($exampleMap, "bar", "barfoo") //barfoo
```

**Nested map:**

```
@debug map-deep-get($exampleMap, "bar", "barbar") //("barbarfoo": barbarfoo)
```

**Nested nested item:**

```
@debug map-deep-get($exampleMap, "bar", "barbar", "barbarfoo") //barbarfoo
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, nowadays you can directly use **map-get** to get nested property value:

```
$exampleMap: (
        "foo": 1px,
        "bar": (
                "barfoo": 6px,
                "barbar": (
                        "barbarfoo": orange,
                ),
        ),
);

.h-6 {
  background: map-get($exampleMap, "bar", "barbar", "barbarfoo");
}
```

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/bf2c9476c254493f06fdd761f9d6e798